# How can we query data from two different databases and compare the results using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have two databases located on the same server. How can we write the query part in sql server to extract data from two different databases located on the same server.

Comment: What do you mean by `compare` ? Did you mean that you will just look at the data manually and compare or if you want to get a difference in the number of rows ?

Answer (score 2):

Use 3 part naming:  `[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]`

```
select 
    t1.*,
    t2.* 
from [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] t1
join [MyOtherDatabase].[dbo].[MyOtherTable] t2 on t1.SomeColumn = t2.SomeColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

Fully qualify the table with `DB_NAME.Schema_name.table_name`. For example, if you have database as `DB1` and `DB2` with default schema as `dbo` and table names `tab1`. then you can differentiate between them saying

```
select * from DB1.dbo.tab1
```

OR

```
select * from DB2.dbo.tab1
```